# javascript click event queue

Tags: javascript

I made a simple gallery where when you click on a image thumb nail, it will show the larger image with fade in fade out effect with jquery.

```
$('#thumnail').click(function(){
  $('#piccontainer').fadeOut(function(){
      $('#piccontainer').html('<div> <img src="' + imgsource + '"  /> </div>');
  });

  $('#piccontainer').fadeIn();
});
```

but if i click on a 5 different thumbnails quickly, the large image will fade in fade out for all 5 images.  How can I disable so that lets say i clicked on 5 thumbnails **very quickly**, it should only fadein the last 5th one.  **basicaly how can i stop the queue of the click events?**

thanks for the help.

Comment: Look at the API, but I'd suggest: [`stop(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: .bind will ensure that quick clicks dont get registered until an action is finished http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: i tried the bind, same result.  where would i add stop?  in this case

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at - http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

You could use timeout like this to avoid multiple clicks. Again this is possible to avoid clicks for a small amount of time and not longer.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/Z7w84/

Comment: i'm sure this is a common issue and must be dealt many times.

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition at the top of the function:

```
if ($('#piccontainer').is(":animated")) {
  return false;
}
```

[See Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3nyrn8uu/1/)